# @GeneratedValue seemingly does not auto-generate when the Entity is being added using a POST Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, primary-key, dynamically-generated

This is my Entity class (shortened for obvious reasons):
`Song.java`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "songs", schema = "dbo")
public class Song {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "song_id")
    private Integer songId;

    // other properties and getter setters not needed for the question
}
```

---

Here's my controller (again, shortened for obvious reasons):
`SongsController.java`:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/songs")
public class SongsController {
    
    @Autowired
    private SongRepository songs;

    //GET, DELETE and PUT mappings not neeeded for the question

    //POST: adds a new song to the repository
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public void addSong(@RequestBody(required = true) Song song) throws DuplicateItemException {
        if(songs.existsById(song.getSongId())) {
            throw new DuplicateItemException();  //simplest possible custom exception handler imaginable
        }
        songs.save(song);
    }
}
```

---

Here's my POST request from POSTMAN:

```json
{
    "songName": "Song3",
    "songDuration": "490"
}
```

Here's what the function receives:

```
songName: "Song3"
songDuration: "490"
songId: null
```

---

The Exception that gets thrown is "songId cannot be null". How do I fix this?
My database is PostgreSQL (12.10.1).

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly add strategy to generated value. Otherwise it will not work. Try this:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Comment: same error :( what exactly does AUTO entail?

Comment: @justanotherguy try deleting your created table. And then again run it. Should be okay.

Comment: Nope man :( Still the same

Answer (score 0):

Your `@GeneratedValue` is missing how to generate the value! Given that you're using PostgreSQL and such RDMS allows the creation of [database sequences](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-create-sequence/), I'll suggest the following configuration ... In your `Song` class, you need to add the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation and make the following changes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "songs", schema = "dbo")
@SequenceGenerator(
    name         = "<AnyNameThatFitsYou>",
    sequenceName = "<TheNameOfYourDatabaseSequence>",
    initialValue = <DatabaseSeqInitVal>,
    allocationSize = <HowManyOfTheseValuesShouldBeAllocatedInJPAMemoryForFastAccess>
)
public class Song {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
        generator = "<TheNameYouGiveToTheSequenceGenerator>",
        strategy  = GenerationType.SEQUENCE
    )
    @Column(name = "song_id")
    private Integer songId;

    // other properties and getter setters not needed for the question
}
```

That should be all ...

Comment: But, why is it so that when I directly add a value in the database, it generates the songId on its own? The datatype I have chosen (in the database table) is `bigserial`.

Comment: `<TheNameOfYourDatabaseSequence>` I haven't created one explicitly (at least to my knowledge; sorry first time on PostgreSQL and Spring Boot)

Comment: `<DatabaseSeqInitVal>`. How do I set this? Won't it reset in the application on each restart when it actually should be 1 plus the last Id (or at least in some relation to the last Id)?

Comment: I tried the solution, but I still get the same error

Comment: That's weird ... However, to answer your first question, is because the type you chose for your song_id column ... this articule may be helpful for you: https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-serial-column-hibernate-identity

Comment: Read the article and the other links that it provided ... I think it answer many of your doubts ... By the way, database sequence do not reset when the application is restarted ...

Comment: I have. I still haven't been able to fix this issue. Are you sure my POSTMAN request is not at fault?

Comment: That depends: I'm assuming that the exception is being thrown during the `save` sentence, Is this right? or it is being thrown in other part of your code??

Comment: No, it's the `save` method

Comment: I see no problems with the POSTMAN request ... By the way, if you read the articule, that means that you try the `GenerationType.IDENTITY` right?

Comment: Yes, I did try it

Comment: I have no idea what is happening ... the other thing I'd suggest (and this is a wild guess), based on the fact that your using `bigserial` in your database, is replacing `private Integer songId` for `private Long songId` ... Maybe Spring/Hibernate is detecting that your attribute does no have the right space to store the value from the database and that could be the reason why always end `null` ...

Comment: I have changed almost everything, and yet I get the [same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71261346/generatedvalue-annotation-does-not-help-when-used-in-conjunction-with-requestb)