# @GeneratedValue annotation does not help when used in conjunction with @RequestBody

Tags: java

My Entity class (MRE):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "songs", schema = "playmymusic")
public class Song {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "song_id")
    private Integer songId;

    //Assume some more methods and a Getter and Setter for each
}
```

My RestController method:

```java
//POST: adds a new song to the repository
@PostMapping("/add")
public void addSong(@RequestBody(required = true) Song song) throws DuplicateItemException {
    if(songs.existsById(song.getSongId())) {
        throw new DuplicateItemException();
    }
    songs.save(song);
}
```

[My POSTMAN POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnPBX.png)

Text:

```json
{
    "songName": "Song4",
    "songAlbumId": "1",
    "songDuration": 300
}
```

Error: Id must not be null. What have I done wrong?

PS: The error is [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71191728/generatedvalue-seemingly-does-not-auto-generate-when-the-entity-is-being-added) but the DBMS is different (MySQL) and I do not even have a custom generator in place this time

Comment: can you please update your question and add all fields in the `Song` Class? Moreover, your request contains a field `songAlbumId` but your class it has `song_id` only, Are these different?

Comment: yes. songAlbumId is a foreign key for the primary key albumId in the albums table

Answer (score 0):

If you use the strategy javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY for **@GeneratedValue** your table must have an identity generator. This can be done including an **AUTO_INCREMENT** to your primary key.

alter primary key of existing table to make it Auto Incremented.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
MODIFY column_name INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: I've tried that already. That does not help