# @GeneratedValue not generating anything on insert

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

When I insert a record to the table, I need a uuid field to be auto-generated on insert; I tried multiple methods which end up not doing anything, and it just inserts the record with uuid being null.

Previous issue (Not answered/Answers don't apply): [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71191728/generatedvalue-seemingly-does-not-auto-generate-when-the-entity-is-being-added)

My Entity:

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(length = 36)
    private String uuid;

    @Column(name="firstName", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    ...  
 
    // (getters and setters omitted to be concise)

}
```

What I tried:

1.

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(length = 36)
    private String uuid;
```

2. 

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
    private UUID id;
```

3. 

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID uuid;
```

None of the above worked; I made sure to drop table for it to be re-created but alas. I am new to this framework, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Is it only the uuid that's not inserted? Does everything else work as intended?

Comment: Apologies for delay in response, but yes everything works fine except the uuid. @Thomas

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly set the generator strategy like:    `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)` ? If that does not work you could set the ID by yourself with a "workaround": `@PrePersist private void prePersist() { this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID() }
`

Comment: I guess I am using an outdated version, GenerationType.UUID did not work; but yes the workaround would do for now. Thank you!

Comment: As far as I remember you need to use JPA 3.1 or higher to use `GenerationType.UUID`. I've just assumed you are running 3.1 or higher ;)